# Include data points in gnuplot smooth

Tags: plot, gnuplot, smoothing

Having data as:

```
38 52.26
41 46.34
42 49.49
```

Using `smooth` lines; can I include the points on the graph line without plotting it twice?

Now I use:

```
plot "foo.dat" using ($0):2 smooth csplines title "foo", \
               '' using ($0):2 with points title ""
```

[image: Sample graph]

Extended simplified data set:

```
38     52.26
39     46.34
42     57.29
43     60.41
44     53.57
45     51.49
46     48.24
49     58.50
50     56.85
51     55.56
52     62.81
54     51.76
55     46.94
56     46.35
57     52.76
59     49.49
62     51.78
63     48.24
65     54.46
66     50.00
```

Comment: You could try `with linespoints`, but I'm not sure if that would do what you want.  (I'd need a full datafile to experiment with it).  Is there anything wrong with the extra line of code?  In other words, do you want your plot to look differently?  If yes, what would you want to change about it?  We might be able to work with that if you give more detail about what you're looking for.

Comment: @mgilson: Yes `with linespoints` is not what I want as that set points at given point interval - and not at "data points". It is nothing wrong with "that extra line" but wondered if there was a cleaner/more correct way to do it.

Comment: In that case, I would say that there is not a cleaner way to do it (other than to say `'' using ($0):2 with points notitle ` instead of `title ""` for the second plot.)

Comment: @mgilson: OK. Thank you. Add it as an answer and I'll accept :) (P.s.: the *"Extended simplified data set"* was a bit stupid as column 1 is not consecutive. (It is typically 1 2 4 7, not 1 2 3 4 5 6 7). - edited now for ref.) The `notile` was good - `title ""` looks more as a hack and is ambiguous in code.

Answer (score 7):

This is my way to do it:

```
...
plot "file" using 1:3 notitle with points linestyle 1, \
     "" using 1:3 notitle smooth csplines with lines linestyle 1, \
     1 / 0 title "title" with linespoints linestyle 1
...
```

[image]

The first entry plots the points on the graph, without a legend.
The second entry plots the smoothed line on the graph, again without a legend.
The third entry is just for the legend, using the combined linespoints.

If you use linespoints on the smoothed line, it will show all the points making it smooth, not just the datapoints.

'linestyle' tells gnuplot to plot all the data using the same style, basically compositing the lines and the points to make linespoints.  The third line, the 'linespoints', is just for the legend, and does not put any data on the plot.

Comment: Regardless of if this works or not, please try to also include some explanation with your code. A high quality answer will not only give a solution but explain how it works / why you do it that way.